# JQuery fade backup to CSS transitions - Modernizr

Tags: jquery, effects, modernizr, css-transitions

I have written an image gallery using CSS transitions. If CSS transitions cannot be used as picekd up by modernizr plugin it defaults to a fade in and out effect. This effect is not working at all. Can anyone see a problem with the code. The CSS3 version is fully functional.

EDIT

I have remade it to addClass and removeClass similar to how web-kit works. The JQuery function is now functional with no console errors. It is not particularly fluid though. With CSS-3 transitions if the user clicks multiple thumbnails the images will gently transition even if they are half way through an effect. The JQuery seams to clog up and then start jumping about.

Any ideas on this.

```
    var timerp = null;
        var nextslide;


        if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
            $('.thumbs').click(function() {
        if (timerp) {
            window.clearInterval(timerp);
        }
        $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus',{queue:true,duration:2000});
        $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus',{queue:true,duration:2000});
        gallery();
    });
        function gallery() {
            timerp = window.setInterval(function() {
                var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
                islide.removeClass('cornerimgfocus',{queue:true,duration:2000});

                if (islide[0] == $('.cornerimg:last')[0]) {
                    nextslide =  $('.cornerimg').first();
                } else {
                    nextslide = islide.next();
                };
                nextslide.addClass('cornerimgfocus',{queue:true,duration:2000});
            }, 6000);
        }
}
        else {
        $('.thumbs').click(function() {
        if (timerp) {
            window.clearInterval(timerp);
        }
        $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
        $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus');
        gallery();
    });

        function gallery() {
            timerp = window.setInterval(function() {
                var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
                islide.removeClass('cornerimgfocus');

                if (islide[0] == $('.cornerimg:last')[0]) {
                    nextslide =  $('.cornerimg').first();
                } else {
                    nextslide = islide.next();
                };
                nextslide.addClass('cornerimgfocus');
            }, 6000);
        }
}
```

Comment: _"Not working at all"_ **needs more detail.** Any errors in the console? Do demons fly out of your eSATA port when attempting to run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All figured out.

[JQuery Image Gallery fading not always working and IE tragedy - solve a fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539420/jquery-image-gallery-fading-not-always-working-and-ie-tragedy-solve-a-fiddle/6539866#6539866)

Marvellous,

Comment: Possibly the first cross browser including mobile support always smooth thumbnailed slideshow fade gallery